# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported nesting ANONYMOUS kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to update all of my plugins version to the latest one, but I get error :

> Execution failed for task ':app:hiltJavaCompileDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported nesting ANONYMOUS

here is my gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.43.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.2"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

&

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.test"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "apps")
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", base_url
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "API_BASE_URL", base_url
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2"

    /* hilt viewmodel extension*/
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

I'm trying to solve the issue but nothing happens. Is there something not compatible with the latest update for the hilt version ? Or do I miss something from my gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your hilt gradle plugin, it solve my problem.

> classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"